# Which data type can i use for this?

Tags: java

In Java. I want to store user defined object and an integer related to it. Which data type should i use?
I have tried HashMap, but apparently it cant store objects without equals() method

Comment: The good question is: what must you do with these objects and this integer? Quickly find an integer based on a given object? Quickly find an object based on an integer? Iterate through the object-integer pairs? Have the objects sorted by their associated integer?

Comment: `HashMap` absolutely *can* store objects which don't override equals/hashCode... you'll just get reference identity behaviour. Now, how do you *want* it to behave?

Comment: Why is overriding `equals` and `hashCode` a problem?

Comment: You can put object in hashmap without overriding equals method. Show us your code?

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried HashMap, but apparently it cant store objects without
>   equals() method

More precisely, you can't use an object as key of your Map, without satisfying either of the below two conditions: -

- Override both `equals` and `hashcode`, or
- Override none of them.

So, you can easily use your object as key, without using equals method as per the second condition.

But, it's better to follow the first condition if you want your key to be found based on a newly created object. Because the default implementation of `equals` method compare *reference values* of objects rather than the *content* itself.

Comment: Even if you override either equals or hashcode it will work fine

Comment: @rai.skumar.. Of course as far as storing objects is concerned it will work fine. But you will never get your key back from the Map again.

Comment: suppose if i just override equals. In this case 2 equal object might be hashed to different location but you will be able to recover your object as equals is overriden.

Comment: @rai.skumar: If two equal objects are hashed to two different locations, you have a serious bug. The HashMap is not supposed to contain two keys if those keys are equal. It's supposed to contain only one. you MUST override hashCode if you override equals.

Comment: yeah..agree, but specification doesn't force me to do that. I am free to just override equals and yes i know its implication. I agree that its not good practice.

Comment: Of course. You can also implement every method by throwing UnsupportedOperationException, or break the documented contract of every method you implemnt, but you won't build any useful program doing that. It's not just a bad practice. It's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You should stick to the hash map.It works fine for all cases.

Here is some class defined by user

```
   public class UserDefinedObject(){
    }
```

---

And here is the usage of this class with HashMap

```
import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<UserDefinedObject, Integer> stuff = new HashMap<UserDefinedObject, Integer>();
        UserDefinedObject userDefinedObject = new UserDefinedObject();
        stuff.put(userDefinedObject, 1);
        System.out.println(stuff.get(userDefinedObject));
    } 
}
```